# Push down nth image

Tags: html, css

I have 4 image elements, and I would like to push down all elements after element nr. 2

So instead of getting:

```
| | | |
```

I would get:

```
| |
| |
```

I'm using `img:nth-child(2)` to position the element, and it does work. But I have problem pushing the following elements down. I thought `clear: right` would do this, but it doesn't work.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zXteb/

Comment: How about setting the width on the containing div to something like 210px? http://jsfiddle.net/zXteb/2/

Comment: Images are not block elements unless you tell them to be, so just using `clear` on them will have no effect.

Comment: Do you mean all images after 2 (`nth-child(1n+3)`) or only after every second (`nth-child(2n+1)`)?

Comment: 2n+1 or 2, doesn't matter, I always have 4 images, never more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without float & clear. There's a very cool trick with a newline in `content`:

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/By2sD/1/

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 500px;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(2n+2):after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

The `\A` is a newline character and the `white-space: pre` makes it a `<br>`. All elements are inline, so you can center the whole thing

Comment: Thank Lea: http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/flexible-multiline-definition-lists-with-2-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 3):

You have to float images to make `clear` work:

```
div img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

div img:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zXteb/1/

Comment: Thank you for this, but I'm having trouble with this float solution and aligning all the images in center of a parent div.

Comment: You don't need floats: http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/flexible-multiline-definition-lists-with-2-lines-of-css/ but somehow this method doesn't work for me anymore... It used to, but now it doesn't. Weird!?

Comment: No it still works without float, centering: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/By2sD/1/

Answer (score -1):

This is how it goes
In HTML use--

```
<div id="one">
    <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</div>
<div id="two">
    <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</div>    
<div id="three">     
    <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</div>            
<div id="four">
    <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</div>
```

And the css will go like this

```
#one {
    float:left;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#two {
    float:left;
}
#three {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#four {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: What if you have 17 `img`s?

Comment: Make what a class? `class="odd"` or something? You should mention that in your answer.

Comment: i was giving answer to that particular question not for all the inclusive cases.

Comment: I was expecting this from you, thanx alot. Instead you could better explained me where i'm going wrong since i'm a learner not an expert.

Comment: I actually didn't -1 you =) Your answer is not bad, it's just not optimal. The class idea isn't bad at all (and very common), so you should update your answer, so I can +1 it.

Comment: Ok sir, but i didn't bother about increasing my reputation rather i want to learn here. Thanx for your reply i will try to improve myself.